# latest Django is not supporting imports for models from other app. please give me solution for that

Tags: django-models, django-2.0

As i am importing models from other app by 
from projectname.app1.models import model1

it says for projectname.app1 ModuleNotFounderror

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYuIS.jpg

Comment: What version of django are you using? Also, can you post the exact error?

Comment: Django 2.1 And error is ModuleNotFoundError: no module named "project.app1" ,as I am importing: from project.app1.models import model1

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

For recent Django There is no need to write import (while using models of other app) 
Eg. Suppose in app1 I am having user model. In app2, article model. 
In article model using user as foreign key as, 
user= models.ForeignKey('app1.user', on_detele= models.CASCADE)